# how to efficiently link lines of numpy array to sets of tags?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to convert a list of data structure, all of the same type,  into a numpy arrays. It works well for all the number attributes but there is one attribute whose value is a set of tags (strings). And I don't see how to model that properly with numpy .

So far, I use a 2d array. Each row contains the attributes of one data structure, one per columns. But for the set of strings, I don't know how to use that in a numpy array.

It seems that I can put a set as the value for a cell in the array but It seems to break the point of numpy : fixed size arrays with efficient functions that apply on them.

Any idea ?

Comment: What do you need to do with these string tags?  Why do you need an 'efficient' link?  You'll need to be more specific.  (And 'set' is not the right term here; list maybe, or array of strinrgs).

Comment: Numpy structured arrays let you mix string fields and numeric ones.  They are a natural result of reading mixed columns from a `csv`.  `pandas` uses a table concept with labeled rows and columns.  But the core numpy calculations work best with unlabeled rows and columns.

Comment: @hpaulj these tags are used for filtering. each row can be associated with a set of them. I could make add a column  to the arrray and put the set there, but it seems there is no function in numpy for filtering based on a set of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best alternative is to use a list of tuples

Supposing l is your list:

```
In [1]: l = [[4,5,6,'a','b'],['x','y',2,3]]
In [2]: _l = [tuple(elem) for elem in l]
In [3]: _l
Out[1]: [(4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b'), ('x', 'y', 2, 3)]
```

Alternatively you could create a list of tuple where the first element of the tuple is the numpy array, and the second element is the tag.

Comment: numpy arrays can store strings, even general objects. And there's a compound `dtype`.  But the calculation possibilities are limited.